# Google Cloud - No secret key for reCAPTCHA Enterprise

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I am trying to create a reCAPTCHA secret key and I already enabled the reCAPTCHA Enterprise API and created a key.

It created the site key, but I do not see a secret key.

Answer (score 2):

The ReCAPTCHA Enterprise version does not use a secret key for back-end authentication, it creates a key using the GCP's service account instead. You can check the complete step by step instruction [here](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/install-on-gcp#creating-a-service-account-for-backend-authentication).

If you need to use a `secret key` for your use case, you will need to use `reCAPTCHA v2/v3` instead. Below is the procedure how to do so:

1. Log on to your Google account.
2. Access https://www.google.com/recaptcha/adminInformation from your browser.
3. Select the chosen reCAPTCHA version.
4. Register your domain.
5. Save your Site key and your Secret key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid creating a service account when creating a reCAPTCHA Enterprise assessment, you can use GPC's REST API to obtain API key and limit it to interact with the reCAPTCHA Enterprise only.

More details at:

[Create an assessment using the REST API or Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment#create_API_client_libraries)

Answer (score -2):

The Admin Console allows you to view your reCAPTCHA site key and secret key, and configure the settings of your reCAPTCHA keys at any time. It also allows you to permanently delete your reCAPTCHA keys.

[Creating reCAPTCHA Keys](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key)

[reCAPTCHA Seetings](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/settings)

Follow the links above to guide you with your reCAPTCHA key generation and management.

Comment: the ReCAPTCHA enterprise version does not use a secret key for back-end auth.